Network Bridge Not Working After Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Update
I am currently using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (latest version), and before the update, I was running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (maybe). My setup includes a GUI, and I use Virt-Manager to host VMs.
After the update, my previous netplan configuration stopped working, and I lost internet connectivity on the host machine. Below is the previous configuration:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth1]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [103.192.157.246/28]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 103.192.157.241 
        metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [103.84.36.5]
      dhcp6: no
      link-local: [ ]
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0

I require a proper bridge configuration to assign an IP address to my VMs, but I haven’t gotten this working.
Here is the configuration I’m currently using, which allows the host to connect to the internet but does not work with the bridge setup I need.
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    NM-2f5257fe-8930-34b9-aca3-549d092c0943:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "eth1"
      addresses:
      - "103.192.157.246/24"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 103.84.36.5
      dhcp6: true
      wakeonlan: true
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "2f5257fe-8930-34b9-aca3-549d092c0943"
        name: "Wired connection 2"
        passthrough:
          connection.autoconnect-priority: "-999"
          ethernet._: ""
          ipv4.address1: "103.192.157.246/24,103.192.157.241"
          ipv4.method: "manual"
          ipv6.addr-gen-mode: "default"
          ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
          proxy._: ""

Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Old Config: Bitmask /28, New Config /24 Valid or Mistake?  NetworkManager has your address range as .241 to .246 due to the way your subnet is being read.

Thank you very much for your reply. I have spent 3 days on this but still have not reached a solution. I have also tried 24 and 28, and both work without the bridge. After adding the bridge, the connection was lost.

Delete everything you've done and start and read Virtual Networking in Linux. Follow every step to the  letter regardless if you've done it a million times before.  The Object here is to bridge the virtual port to the tap device, and then point the VM to the bridge.  I think you've forgotten the TAP device

I was struggling all day with the same problem. I don't have an answer based of understanding, but rather just brute force. I am not sure which of the following things actually helped.

I switched from NetworkManager to networkd. I am not sure if this was helpful or not. If you are interested, the instructions are provided sourced from this page. I also tried some of the other things in here like using virsh to create a network connected to the bridge. But that just seemed to give me network access rather than full internet access. I was successful when I just linked to the bridge directly.

# enable as services on startup
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service

# start services
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd.service

# check status
systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
systemctl status systemd-networkd.service

# disable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service


I copied and pasted the format below from this site into my netplan config file and made only the smallest changes possible (mac address, static ip address, and ethernet names. It was the only schema I found that worked, even though I swore I tried a very similar configuration with my modified plan. The only differences I can think of is perhaps the fact that it doesn't have a resolver, and the bridge had a different name. Or it might be the mac address, although I tried that in a number of unsuccessful configurations.

network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: false
      # disable existing configuration for ethernet
      #addresses: [10.0.0.30/24]
      #routes:
      #  - to: default
      #    via: 10.0.0.1
      #    metric: 100
      #nameservers:
      #  addresses: [10.0.0.10]
      #  search: [srv.world]
      dhcp6: false
  # add configuration for bridge interface
  # [macaddress] ⇒ specify HW address of enp1s0
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp1s0]
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.0.0.30/24]
      macaddress: 52:54:00:db:f8:fe
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.10]
        search: [srv.world]
      parameters:
        stp: false
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2


Other sources that were part of my journey, but I
am not sure how much they really contributed.

Hope it also helps you. Good Luck.

Thanks a lot @Kit! Your solution worked for me. A mismatch between the MAC address of interface and bridge caused the issue. I added the following line:
[mac address: ]
This fixed the problem, and my host is now back online.
However, a new issue has arisen. While the bridge is working, the VM is unable to ping external networks like 8.8.8.8 but it can ping itself and the host IP, and the host can also ping the VM’s IP. The VM is in production mode (a web server) and was functioning properly before. I can also access the VM via SSH from the host without any problems.
